# Natural Join of different tables

Tags: relational-algebra

Could you please explain to me how to do a NATURAL JOIN on these two relations (one having 5 and the other one 3 rows?

1st relation

```
A   C
3   3
6   4
2   3
3   5
7   1
```

2nd relation

```
B   C   D
5   1   6
1   5   8
4   3   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you have two separate relations, which have one attribute (i.e. column) in common: C.

A natural join will combine all tuples in both relations with that attribute in common. You will end up with the results:

```
A B C D    

7 5 1 6  
3 4 3 9
2 4 3 9
3 1 5 8
```

This can be performed in SQL by using the code @Matthew posted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`SELECT * FROM 1stRelation NATURAL JOIN 2ndReleation`

It will do the same thing and an inner join using the explicit column names. I.e.:

`SELECT * from 1stRelation as x INNER JOIN 2ndRelation as z ON x.C=z.C`

Personally - I prefer not to use them except in the possible case where I am not aware of the table structure in advance but know they should be able to be joined.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you do a CROSS JOIN, i. e. you combine every row from the 1st relation with every row of the 2nd relation. Then you have two C columns. Now you eliminate every row where the two C are *not equal* and merge them as only one column C.